# How to get the current savedInstanceState in an AsyncTask callback?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I ran into an interesting problem, and I'm not sure how to go about fixing it. Consider the following code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Bundle savedState;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        savedState = savedInstanceState;
        Log.d("ON CREATE", "savedState is null: "+(savedState==null));
        new CustomTask().execute();
    }

    public class CustomTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
            Log.d("POST EXECUTE", "savedState is null: "+(savedState==null));
        }
    }
}
```

This code saves a reference to the `savedInstanceState` then runs an AsyncTask, which tries to access that variable 5 seconds later. If the user changes the orientation of the device before the AsyncTask finishes its work, the following output is produced:

```
ON CREATE: savedState is null: true //initial run
ON CREATE: savedState is null: false //re-created after orientation change
POST EXECUTE: savedState is null: true //first instance
POST EXECUTE: savedState is null: false //second instance
```

Both of the `onPostExecute()` methods fire after the orientation change, but they are seemingly accessing the same `savedState` variable, which I expected to be non-null in both cases since it was being accessed after the orientation change.

Apparently the first AsyncTask, which was started before the orientation change still references the `savedState` variable from before the change as well. So my questions are:

Why does it do this? After the app state is restored, I would expect the AsyncTask to simply access all class members in their current states, which means `savedState` would be non-null.

And how can I access the current `savedInstanceState` variable from the callback of an AsyncTask that was started before that variable was changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a month of dealing with this issue, I finally found the solution to this. The key concept I was struggling with was how to update an (already running) AsyncTask with a reference to the current instance of the Activity it's working with. Here's how to do it.

The first step is to separate the AsyncTask into its own class file, and pass a reference to the Activity it's working with in through a constructor or a setter. So to use the same example I used in my original question, it would look something like this:

```
public class CustomTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    //This could also be a reference to a callback interface
    //implemented in an Activity
    private Activity activity;  

    public CustomTask(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }       

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
        Log.d("POST EXECUTE", "savedState is null: "+(savedState==null));
    }

    //newly added method
    public void setActivity(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    //newly added method
    public void detachFromActivity() {
        activity = null;
    }
}
```

The next step is to save a reference to the running AsyncTask as a data member of the Activity. That's just a matter of creating a private variable `private CustomTask customTask;` in the Activity.

Next, and this is the important part, you need to override `onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance()` in your Activity, and in this method, detach the AsyncTask from its old Activity (which is destroyed on a screen rotation) and retain the reference to the task so we can work with it in the new instance of the Activity that will be re-created when the screen finishes rotating. So this method would look like this:

```
@Override
public Object onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance() {
    if(customTask != null) {
        customTask.detachFromActivity();
    }
    return customTask;
}
```

Now, after the screen rotation has completed and the Activity is re-created, we need to get the reference to our task that was passed through. So we call `getLastCustomNonConfigurationInstance()` and cast the Object it returns to our specific AsyncTask class type. We can do a null check here to see if we have a task that was passed through. If there is one, we set its listener to our CURRENT Activity reference, so that the callbacks come to the right Activity instance (and hence avoided NullPointerExceptions, IllegalStateExceptions, and other nasties). This bit should look like this:

```
customTask = (CustomTask) getLastCustomNonConfigurationInstance();
if(customTask != null) {
    customTask.setListener(this);
}
```

Now our running AsyncTask has the correct reference to the current instance of our Activity, and it will properly deliver its callbacks to an up-to-date Activity.

For more information on the uses and limitations of this solution, please see the Android documentation here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()

Answer (score 1):

After the orientation change, there are two instances of `MainActivity`.  The old one has gone through the tear-down lifecycle events (`onStop()`, `onDestroy()`, etc.) but has not been garbage collected because the inner-class `CustomTask` thread is still running and holds a reference to it. That instance of `CustomTask` sees the null `savedState`.  It knows nothing of the new instance of `MainActivity`, created after the restart, and its non-null `savedState`.

Do you really want the original instance of `CustomTask` to continue running after restart? Maybe you should cancel it when the activity is destroyed.  If you really need it to continue running and have access to state data that you now declare in the activity, you will need to move that state data out of the activity to somewhere else, such as a singleton object, subclass of `Application` or persistent storage.

Using a [retained fragment](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#RetainingAnObject) might be another option for retaining state and background processing across restarts.

Comment: Well the larger context of this problem is that I have a web service request library I built a while ago to make some soap requests and parse the results. I'm just trying to do some fragment transactions when the request callback comes in, so I was wanting to access the `savedInstanceState` Bundle to access a Fragment I put there. But I think your persistent storage suggestion might be the best option. Maybe I'll try throwing it in shared prefs and access it from there.